# Google Voice forwading failover

Tags: google, google-voice

Is it possible to have a Google Voice call, which is forwarded to my phone, forward to *another* user's phone if i am unable to answer the call?

Thanks for any and all replies.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this just like with any other call via Call Forwarding.  From [Dummies.com](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-forward-calls-on-an-android-phone.html):

> **1. Open the Phone app.**
>
> **2. Touch the Action Overflow icon.**
>
> [image: image0.jpg]
>
> On some phones, touch the Menu icon instead to see a list of commands.
>
> **3. Choose Settings or Call Settings.**
>
> The Call Settings command might be found on a second screen; choose Settings first, and then choose Call Settings. Eventually you’ll see the call settings screen.
>
> **4. Choose Call Forwarding.**
>
> If the option isn’t available, use your cellular carrier to forward calls.
>
> **5. Choose one of the following options:**
>
> - *Always Forward:* All incoming calls are sent to the number you specify; your phone doesn’t even ring. This option overrides all other forwarding options.
> - *Forward When Busy:* Calls are forwarded when you’re on the phone and choose not to answer. This option is normally used to send a missed call to voicemail, although you can forward to any number.
> - *Forward When Unanswered:* Calls are forwarded when you choose not to answer the phone. Normally, the call is forwarded to your voicemail.
> - *Forward When Unreached:* Calls are forwarded when the phone is turned off, out of range, or in airplane mode. As with the two previous settings, this option normally forwards calls to voicemail.
>
> **6. Set the forwarding number.**
>
> Or you can edit the number that already appears. For example, you can type your home number for the Forward When Unreached option so that your cell calls are redirected to your home number when you’re out of range.
>
> **7. Touch Enable or OK.**
>
> [image: image1.jpg]